# Hackerrank not accepting valid solution

Tags: java, string.format

The [(HakerRank) task](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-output-formatting/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) is for me to format the input given by test cases.

There needs to be 15 spaces between the string and integers and append a zero in-front of the integer should there only be two digits, my code accomplishes this to the best of my knowledge and matches the expected output however my code is still considered incorrect.

May I have some assistance figuring out why?

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            String s1=sc.next();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            int length = String.valueOf(x).length();
            if(length < 3) {
                System.out.format("%-15s %03d %n", s1, x );
            } else {
                System.out.format("%-15s %d %n", s1, x );
            }
        }
        System.out.println("================================");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like/use Hackerrank often, but my guess is that there are some inefficiencies or maybe edge cases you are missing.

Comment: Thanks, no turns out all I needed to do was get rid of whitespace in my formatting terms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the white spaces in the string format, like this:

```
// ...
if(length < 3) {
    System.out.format("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x);
} else {
    System.out.format("%-15s%d%n", s1, x);
}
// ...
```

And it passes all the tests :)